# B01s brake pads

Tags: mountain-bike

Can anyone tell the significance of letters stamped/printed on brake pads? E.g. `Nd` and `Hw` circled, also the words `sl21 /22`.

The Shimano B01s resin pads on my MTB have these marks. How to find the proper replacement?

Comment: Your question has been answered so I guess it was clear enough. But it might help other people who are interested in replacement brake pads if you included a phto of your pads, so they can see what markings you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

B01S pads are a line of pads made by Shimano, and is compatible with various brakes. [Chain Reaction Cycles](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/shimano-acera-altus-b01s-disc-brake-pads/rp-prod130772) Lists:

> Shimano BR-C501 -  BR-M485 - BR-M445 - BR-M395 - BR-TX805 - BR-M575 - BR-M475 - BR-M416 - BR-M375 - BR-M525 - BR-M465 - BR-M416A - BR-M355 - BR-M495 - BR-M447 - BR-M415 - BR-T675 - BR-M486 - BR-M446 - BR-M4050 - BR-T615.

The pad has been around for a while, so you may see different compatibility lists depending on retailer.

If you're looking for replacement pads, you're better off identifying what brake model you have, and then looking for a compatible brake pad based on that. For example, some Tektro's can run this pad, but you won't see them in the list above.

If you're using some no name brake, look at brakes compatible with the models listed above, and they should (hopefully) fit. Or, take the pads and/or bike to the bike shop and they should set you up.